# What are the particular words for the first iteration of things?

Tags: words

Does anyone know the sorts of items for whose first iteration Japanese people have special names? The only example I can remember at the moment is for the first leader or, to be precise, (and reveal the place I learned it), the first Hokage, 初代. Google Translate gives me a vast number of words, all essentially forms of "progenitor," for that particular kanji combination.

So, are there other "first" things for which Japanese people have special names? I'm aware that the Japanese culture places special importance on the first of anything, e.g., the first sunrise of the year, so I was hoping someone could list the Japanese names of a few of the more famous such things. Looking at counter dictionaries online hasn't helped me find any, and I've now (possibly mistakenly) come to realize that these names are independent of the counter system.

Answer (score 3):

The ones you're looking for usually start with [「[初]{はつ・しょ・うい}」](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%88%9D&eng=&dict=edict&tag=&sortorder=relevance) or [「[発]{はつ}」](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%99%BA&eng=&dict=edict&tag=&sortorder=relevance).

> 初荷    はつに     first cargo of the year
>   初音  はつね     first warbling heard in a New Year
>   発刊  はっかん    publish; start (new) publication
>   発会  はっかい    opening a meeting; first meeting

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add [元]{がん} to Ignacio's answer.

> 元旦 'the morning of the first day of the year'
>   元年 'the first year of a calender system or an era'

Comment: Although some people use 元旦 as the first day of the year, it usually means the _morning_ of the first day of the year.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Thanks for correcting me. I mistook the word.

Answer (score 1):

Just some random *very* commonly used ones I thought of

- 初産{ういざん}  First birth
- 初詣{はつもうで} First shrine visit of the year
- ファーストキス First kiss
- 初体験{はつたいけん} First experience
- 初対面{しょたいめん} First time you meet someone
- 初婚{しょこん} First marriage
- 書初{かきぞ}め First calligraphy writing of the year
- 馴{な}れ初{そ}め How you first met/got to know each other (used a lot at weddings)

Comment: To add my 2 cents, I've heard "first kiss" はつキス too ^^

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. For fun, I just wanted to throw in an example where the English loanword is as common as the (half) Japanese one.