# How can I talk about old memories and important "firsts"?

Tags: translation

How can I say old memories and first (talk, hug, kiss) kind of stuff?

Comment: Related: [What are the particular words for the first iteration of things?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4520/542)

Answer (score 6):

Use `初【はつ】(の)〜` or `初めての〜`.

> 初デート　→　First date
>   初恋【はつこい】　→　First love
>   初めての[経験]{けいけん}　→　First experience

Comment: How about 初体験 for first experience? :D

Comment: @Chocolate:  I don't know, is that a real word?

Comment: @istrasci It used to be a neutral word, but often (after the influence of the TV program 夏・体験物語 in 1985), it carries a particular connotation.

Comment: @sawa-san, I didn't know that...lol

Comment: @sawa. Pardon my ignorance but what particular connotation would that be?

Comment: @Flaw It means "first sexual experience". But keep in mind that it does not always mean that.

Comment: @Chocolate You didn't know what? About the connotation or about the TV show?

Comment: @sawa-san, I think I know the connotation (hehe...) but have never heard of that TV programme.

Comment: Maybe はつたいけん and しょたいけん have different nuances?

Comment: @Chocolate Maybe generation gap?

Comment: @sawa-san, えええ...いや～そ、それは何とも...(^_^;)